# Sync database of umbraco in other environments

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have 3 environments for develop Umbraco (Dev - Staging - Production). How can i Sync 3 database of environments with what i develop, example: Document Type, some structure not data like Content.

Comment: At my company we use https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/utransporter/ and i have used Umbraco Courier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at uSync here: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync/

"uSync in an umbraco package that takes the bits of umbraco that are stored in a database and moves them to disk, so you can source control, copy and move your umbraco site between computers and servers."

Comment: Hi Anker, thank for response , uSync is not sync database where store the structure when i develop, I need a tool to handle what changed in database.

Comment: uSync IS exactly a way to sync changes in databases!? It does so by extracting your dev changes into files that you can then import onto staging and production environments. Are you looking for an actual database tool to sync databases directly, like http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/ ?

Comment: Thank @Jannik Anker, i look back and deep research about uSync, it is what i need.

Answer (score 2):

Can't believe nobody has mentioned Courier. This is the de facto tool for the job you are talking about.

With past versions of Umbraco, Courier has had its fair share of problems but these days, it does an excellent job.

The express version @ 99€ is sufficient for most purposes.

http://umbraco.com/products-and-support/courier/

Comment: Courier seems to be a bit complex for what OP wants, or at least that was my thought. Haven't used either :-/

Comment: Courier will work OOTB, uSync is definitely more complex to set up. You can use Courier to ship whatever Umbraco changes you want, be it content, doc types or whatever.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then!

Comment: I'd say if you only want to sync structure - uSync would most likely do what you need. If you want any kind of deployment of content/media (and dependencies like the structure, datatypes and such) Courier is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah it will work but it outputs files to the file system that then need to be pushed to each environment where usync needs to be run again.  That's fine if that can be worked into your deployments. Couriering changes (in U7) has been a good experience so far and does not require as much work.